# Gallery not showing images

Tags: samsung-mobile

I'm using an S Note 4 and my gallery isn't working.

My gallery won't show anything, none of my images are showing up even though I had hundreds and now they have all suddenly vanished even though I can see them in the data folders, it happened to a friend of mine but he hasn't fixed it either. Would anyone here know how to fix this?

Comment: is this the right place to ask??

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure but I was told online just to put it here anyway...

Comment: may be this is more relevant http://android.stackexchange.com/